# Как скрыть ненужный элемент? if (... показать одно) else показать другое и скрыть первое и наоборот?

Tags: javascript

Если задать значения один раз и нажать на кнопку вычисления, то выдаёт одну картинку правильно. Если задать параметры ещё раз и нажать вычислить, то он не удаляет первую картинку а добавляет вторую.

Как сделать чтобы показывало только один результат?

```js
if (ss[a1] > ss[a2]) {
  document.getElementById('img1').innerHTML =
    "<img src=\"images/img1/" + goimage[a1] + "-result.png\" alt=\"" + "\" />";
} else {
  document.getElementById('img2').innerHTML =
    "<img src=\"images/img2/" + goimage2[a1] + "-result.png\" alt=\"" + "\" />";
}
```

```html
<div id="img1">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="img2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Пробовал вставлять в `else: div.classList.remove('img1');` 
но не получается

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (ss[a1] > ss[a2]) {
  document.getElementById('img1').innerHTML =
    "<img src=\"images/img1/" + goimage[a1] + "-result.png\" alt=\"" + "\" />";
  document.getElementById('img2').innerHTML = '';
} else {
  document.getElementById('img2').innerHTML =
    "<img src=\"images/img2/" + goimage2[a1] + "-result.png\" alt=\"" + "\" />";
  document.getElementById('img1').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('img1')` - это один элемент.
`document.getElementById('img2')` - это второй элемент.
Они никак не связаны, поэтому innerHTML одного не влияет на innerHTML другого.

Comment: Понимаю что не влияют. Но неужели нельзя сделать чтобы при каждом нажатии на кнопку обнулялся результат и показывался новый, т.е. старый результат стирался.

Comment: Ну так и стирайте ненужный результат, например: `document.getElementById('img1').innerHTML = '';` =)

Answer (score 0):

Если окажется, что первый элемент массива ss больше, чем второй, то показываем черный квадрат. Если меньше, то синий.

```js
const ss = [10, 0];
const img1 = document.querySelector('.img1');
const img2 = document.querySelector('.img2');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (ss[0] > ss[1]) {
    img1.classList.add('show');
    img2.classList.remove('show');
  } else {
    img1.classList.remove('show');
    img2.classList.add('show');
  }
};
```

```css
.img1 {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.img2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1"></div>
<div class="img2"></div>
<button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую )